# Fill in the blank with a suitable form of other

Tags: word-choice

> He has almost finished. He only needs ________ ten minutes.

I think "*other*" for the blank. But the answer key says: It will be "*another*". And I think *another* should be used before a singular noun.

What is the right answer?

Comment: "Other" is a tough one. "Another" is right here because of "ten". If I have time later and someone doesn't beat me to it I'll try and figure out why in an answer.

Comment: If you aren't set on using a form of "other", I'd say a more typical formulation is "he only needs ten more minutes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sentence, *another* is the correct *determiner*.

It marks not the plural noun *minutes* but the *noun phrase* "ten minutes" which, in the context of the sentence, is treated as a single entity.

> He has almost finished. He only needs *another* ten minutes.

It may be convenient to think of the usage as an ellipsis of *period of*:

> He has almost finished. He only needs another [period of] ten minutes.

An insightful answer to a similar question is provided **[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87764/192771)** by StoneyB at our sister site ELU.

Comment: +1. Note that this isn't specific to *another*; we also say e.g. *a good ten minutes*. In general, there aren't many cases where we put the adjective before the numeral, but in (almost?) all of those cases, we need a determiner such as *a*.

Comment: @ruakh Good point. I'll expand a little when time permits.